# enqueue script/style plungin development

Tags: plugin-development

I'm developing my first plugin and wp_enqueue_style doesn't work. I'm in localhost (apache2) installation, ubuntu 14.04.

In my main file I have

```
define( 'EASYDM_CSS_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'css/' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'easydm_add_link_tag_to_head' );
```

And in my php functions file I have:

```
function easydm_add_link_tag_to_head() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style.css', EASYDM_CSS_DIR );
}
```

I want to style an option page, in the admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

You've given `wp_enqueue_style` a directory, but no file name. Have a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/:

- The first parameter of `wp_enqueue_style` is the name, or handle, of the stylesheet as referred to internally by Wordpress (this should be a unique name for each stylesheet you enqueue)
- The second parameter is the src to the stylesheet - so this is where you need to add both your directory and your stylesheet name

So, if you change your second parameter to `EASYDM_CSS_DIR . "style.css"` - and just use something like `'my-stylesheet'` as the first parameter, providing everything is in the right place you should find it works. :)

**EDIT**

Just noticed something I didn't pick up earlier in your code: there's actually no `wp_enqueue_style` action. You need to use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action to add both styles and scripts. This is a bit confusing, because the *function* `wp_enqueue_style` you've used *is* correct, but it's never being called because of the incorrect action.

Change this:

`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'easydm_add_link_tag_to_head' );`

to this:

`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'easydm_add_link_tag_to_head' );`

and then your function `easydm_add_link_tag_to_head` should be called correctly.

If it's still not working, it's probably down to either the path not being correct, or something else I didn't notice in the code! This is where we need to start debugging to find the issue. The simplest, crudest, easiest way to do this is just to put `echo 1;`, `echo 2;`, `echo 3;` etc. in different parts of your code - and then viewing the source of your page - to determine what is working and what isn't. Of course, it's also worth checking if the `<link>` tag is making it through to the source of your page, because if it is, the clue might be in the path not being correct!

Comment: not working too :/
Is there another way to put a link tag in head to style my option page?

Comment: There is, you can do it by hooking into the `wp_head` filter and manually echoing out a `<link />` tag, but it's not recommended - it won't play well with Wordpress core or any plugins. However, I just noticed something I missed before - I've just edited my post to point out an incorrect filter.

Comment: Btw, filters (and actions) can be a bit confusing at first. They allow you to tell Wordpress to run code that changes things (for filters) or does things (for actions) at the correct time in the loading sequence of your page. I highly recommend reading up on filters & actions (eg. maybe http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-beginners-guide-to-wordpress-actions-and-filters--wp-27373) because once you get your head around them, there's lots of powerful stuff you can do with Wordpress.

Comment: Nice, I'm gonna read it now! Thanks. About the problem, I changed _style to _script in add_action enqueue. I echoed  before and after the add_action (echo worked!), but the echos inside the function which should be called didn't work... so the problem is that my function isn't being calling. It is a big help. Really thank you. I let you known about it

Comment: Make sure the action is `wp_enqueue_scripts` - with the s! The function should still be singular.

Comment: yeah, scripts... not working. I read the article but don't understand why my code isn't working. Is there some file which I need to call before to use enqueue or  wp_head? Does the function I'm calling have to return some specific value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36681/discussion-between-tim-malone-and-enrique-rene).

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!!!

The documentation for `wp_enqueue_style` function is clear to say that the second argument nedd to be relative path to the root installation WordPress. But as I viewed many examples in tutorials using full path I ignored it. Now, defining this constant and all previous steps everything runs ok.

`define( 'EASYDM_CSS_PATH' , str_replace( site_url().'/', '', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) ).'css/' );`

and in function:

`wp_enqueue_style( 'easydm-style', '/'.EASYDM_CSS_PATH.'style.css', array(), null, 'all' );`

So, if someone is tired out to looking for and don't wanna read this all discussion, the final code is:

```
define( 'EASYDM_CSS_PATH' , str_replace( site_url().'/', '', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) ).'css/' );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'easydm_add_link_tag_to_head' );
```

functions file:

```
function easydm_add_link_tag_to_head() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'easydm-style', '/'.EASYDM_CSS_PATH.'style.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'easydm-manager', '/'.EASYDM_CSS_PATH.'manager.css', array(), null, 'all' );
}
```

Where I add two styles. I really hope this help someone. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Feel free to click the check mark next to this answer to accept your answer - it means that others that come across will see you have solved it too :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook into `admin_enqueue_scripts` because you want to **style an option page, in the admin panel**.

Add this code and change `css/style.css` with appropriate file path if needed. Hope this works.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'easydm_add_link_tag_to_head' );
function easydm_add_link_tag_to_head(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'enrique_custom', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ). 'css/style.css' );
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the problem was `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )` include http:// ... string and just works without this. But thank you.

Comment: Is there any issue if it includes **http://**?

Comment: I read in here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/ in the $src: "Path to the stylesheet from the root directory of WordPress. Example: '/css/mystyle.css'."
Since everyone writes this, with absolute path stating from http://, I was using this way. But appear repeated "http://domain/http://domain/css/path/style.css" in my href. So I cut this http://... and worked well